# Proof the undecidability of a function (using empty/non-empty intersection)

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I have to proof that my function is undecidable (using empty/non-empty intersection in the reduction).

My function is:  L(G1) = L(G2) = infinite ^ L(G1) ∩ L(G2) /= infinite

I'm thinking about how I can proof it. The theorem says that wether or not the intersection of two CFG's is empty then is undecidable. But in my situation how is possible that the intersection of two sets that are infinite is not infinite and which is the relation with the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose E is the set of all even integers, O is the set of all odd integers and F is some finite set of integers. Take L<sub>1</sub> = E ∪ F and L<sub>2</sub> = O ∪ F. Clearly, L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> are both infinite, and L<sub>1</sub> ∩ L<sub>2</sub> is F, which is finite.

That might help you with the second part of your question, too.

Comment: What do you think of taking the same example and make the intersection of E and O which is empty (/=infinite), and I have L1 and L2 that are infinite (there's an infinite number of odd integers and even integers), so by the theorem I know that is undecidable. Or maybe Im so far of the answer?

Comment: @jack it is not the case that it is always undecidable; obviously it is decidable whether the intersection of even and odd numbers is empty. (As languages, those are both regular languages, and the intersection of two regular grammars is easily computable.) But you asked how two infinite sets could have a finite intersection, and the procedure I used to construct that example might be helpful for your assignment.